# Can't generate correct XSD from XML

Tags: xml, validation, testing, xsd, rest-assured

I've generate some xsd schema from xml response to run my response schema validation tests.

Error message when I'm trying to run my test for response schema validation:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve 'saveResponse' to a type definition for element 'result'.

XML schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="saveResponse">
    <ap_result>ok</ap_result>
    <code>SUCCESS</code>
    <ap_contractNumber>Z6922/240/B0004163/1_TEST</ap_number>
    <ap_insprem>100</ap_insprem>
    <ap_inssum>100000</ap_inssum>
</result>
```

XSD schema that i've generated:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="result">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ap_result"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="code"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ap_number"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="ap_insprem"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:int" name="ap_inssum"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

What should i change in XSD to make my tests work?

Comment: Your XML says that `result` is of type `saveResponse`, yet there is no such type defined in your XSD.  Do you really want to use `xsi:type="saveResponse"` here?   Could you not just use your validation tool's facility to associate your XML with an XSD, or use `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what tool you used to generate the XSD, but it looks as if it takes no account of xsi:type - which isn't really very surprising, since the presence of xsi:type suggests some fairly intricate semantics which can't easily be inferred.

Generating an XSD from one small sample document like this is pretty meaningless. For example, defining a type of xs:byte for ap_insprem is a pretty wild guess: just because the value in your sample is in the range for xs:byte doesn't mean that it must be in this range to be valid.

If all you want to do is generate a schema that this instance conforms to, then you could replace the anonymous complexType with a complexType named saveResponse. But this would be a bit like defining the schema so that "ok" is the only permitted value of ap_result. To do this properly you need to understand the semantics of the document type, which can't be inferred from one example document.